# sql error illegal operation on empty result set using java

Tags: java, sql, mysql-workbench

i want to return a value which i selected from the table but my code does not return any thing and it also give error  Illegal operation on empty result set.
how to remove this error and this program also does not select proper values from table

```
    Connection connection= null ;
    Statement statement = null ;
    ResultSet resultSet= null;
     int cellno=0;
      try
        {


            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","rohma");
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            //resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT idactors,firstname,lastname FROM actors");

              String sql ="SELECT cells FROM abc.projectformat WHERE projectname='"+proj+"' AND projectpassword='"+pass+"';"; 

                 resultSet=statement.executeQuery(sql);
                 if(resultSet.next())
                    {
                        //System.out.print("query executed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //System.out.print("not executed");
                    }
                  cellno =resultSet.getInt("cells");
                //  System.out.print(cellno);
                 //String deletedtable =projectpassword+projectname;
        }

                   catch(SQLException sqlException) 
                   {
                    sqlException.printStackTrace(); 
                   }

                finally
                {
                     try
                     {
                         resultSet.close();
                         statement.close();
                         connection.close();
                     }
                     catch(Exception exception)
                     {

                     }
             }

    return  cellno;

}
```

Comment: Is `abc` in query a alias?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want this code to be corrected, then move this line from its existing position

```
cellno =resultSet.getInt("cells");
```

to inside the `if` block as :

```
if(resultSet.next())
{
    cellno =resultSet.getInt("cells");
    //System.out.print("query executed");
}
```

What the problem with your code is that even if the the `resultSet` was empty the statement `cellno =resultSet.getInt("cells");` got executed. But now when you put it inside the `if` block, if the `resultSet` is empty then it would not execute.

There are many problems in your code. Firstly you are executing the query by directly inserting `string` to the SQL statement. You should use `PreparedStatement` with which you can dynamically insert values to your statement which is less prone to errors.

Secondly if you want to be sure that your query returns only 1 value from the database. You could use 2 nested `if` statements like:

```
if(resultSet.next()){
    if(resultSet.isLast()){
        cellno =resultSet.getInt("cells");
    }else{
        throw new SQLException("More than one row returned");
    }
}else{
    throw new SQLException("No rows returned");
}
```

The advantage of this above code is that if the `resultSet` is empty or has more than 1 rows it will throw an exception by which you can exactly know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if` statement to loop thru your result set which is illogical. Use a `while` loop. Change your code to `while(resultSet.next())`. The code should work as expected if your SQL statement is correct.

**Refer:** [Selecting records from table using JDBC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-records.htm)

Comment: if you use if then only 1st record will be retrieved